# How to delete all rows which have value 1 in "status_pesanan" column

Tags: laravel

I want to delete all rows which have value of 1 in column "status_pesanan" before running create data Laravel

[image]

my controller

```
public function create()
{
    $penjualan = DB::table('penjualan')
            ->groupBy('status_pesanan')
            ->havingRaw('COUNT(status_pesanan) = 1')
            ->delete();

    $penjualan = new Penjualan();    
    $penjualan->nama_pemesan = 1;
    $penjualan['no_nota'] = tambah_nol_didepan($penjualan->no_nota+1, 5);  
    $penjualan->alamat_pemesan = 1;
    $penjualan->telepon_pemesan = 1;
    $penjualan->acc_desain = 1;
    $penjualan->total_item = 0;
    $penjualan->total_harga = 0;
    $penjualan->diskon = 0;
    $penjualan->bayar = 0;
    $penjualan->diterima = 0;
    $penjualan->id_user = auth()->id();
    $penjualan->save();

    session(['id_penjualan' => $penjualan->id_penjualan]);
    return redirect()->route('transaksi-baru.index');
}
```

If I run the code as above, the output I receive is that all old rows in the database are deleted

Comment: That's not what your query is doing, it's deleting when the count is equal to 1, not when the value is equal to 1

Comment: so how to write query correctly? I don't really understand queries

Comment: Well use a `->where('status_pesanan', 1)` without groupBy/havingRaw

Comment: this answer helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by `status_penasan` having its `count` equal to 1 and call `delete` upon it. You wanted to remove the records whose `status_penasan` value is 1. This could be a fix:

```
    $penjualan = DB::table('penjualan')
            ->where('status_pesanan', 1)
            ->delete();
```

Comment: $penjualan = DB::table('penjualan')
            ->where('status_pesanan', 1)
            ->delete();

Comment: @FirdanMahendraWardana thanks, edited my answer accordingly.